# sprite kit - Get notified when a node have been added to a scene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sknode, skscene

I have a subclass of `SKNode` whose I want to get notified when they are added to a scene.
Knowing that `SKNode` have a property called `scene`, I tried to use KVO but for some reason it's not working.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"scene" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"scene"];
}

+ (instancetype)gameWorld
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

#pragma mark - Observer methods

// never called
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == self && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"scene"])
    {
        KKScene *scene = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        NSLog(@"%@", scene);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to get notified when a node have been added to a scene ? Or maybe KVO works well but I did something wrong here ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SKSpriteNode, added to/removed from parent hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648578/skspritenode-added-to-removed-from-parent-hook)

Comment: I understand something since. `scene` property is set only if the scene is the direct parent of the node. I thought even subchilds would have the scene set

Comment: You can observe the parent property of the nodes instead of the scene property.

Comment: @Yaman that is not correct, scene is set for all nodes but only **after** the node has been added as child to another node which in turn is also child of a node that already has a valid scene property (or is the scene itself). Basically the scene property is valid only if the node is actually part of the scene graph. KVO probably didn't work because that property isn't KVO compliant, Sprite Kit behind the scenes is a C++ renderer and bypasses a lot of the Objective-C overhead.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D mhh I see. Thanks for these details !

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this is to have a method which adds nodes and a general subclass of SKNode on which I base all my nodes. This subclass has "-(void)onEnterScene" which is called by the add'er method just after adding it to the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Override this function in your `SKScene` subclass:

```
-(void)addChild:(SKNode *)node {
    [super addChild:node];
    NSLog(@"added child");
}
```

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648578/skspritenode-added-to-removed-from-parent-hook)

Comment: I suppose author wanted to keep modifications inside SKNode subclass, without involving the scene.