# Can a sprite know when it is on the scene?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

I am subclassing SKSpriteNode class to use on a custom sprite. I would like to keep everything as self contained as possible.

Is there a way for a SKSpriteNode know when it is being used on a scene? I mean, suppose another class does this:

```
MySprite *sprite = [[MySprite alloc] init];
```

and ages later does this

```
[self addChild:sprite];
```

Can the sprite know by its own when it is added as a child of some scene or another node?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648578/skspritenode-added-to-removed-from-parent-hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SKNode has an property called scene. If this property returns nil it means it isn't in any scene. You can do the following to check that.

```
if(!MyNode.scene){
    //Do something
}
```

You can also check that at SKNode Doc.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: even this answer not being exactly what I was expecting, it can serve me in another way to do this check on the sprite update method... thanks.

Comment: If you just wanted to know if the sprite is child of someone you can use the property parent (MyNode.parent) instead of scene